# Windows 7 Ultimate Service Pack 1 32 Bits Blender Installation

Tags: blend-files

Which blender version is compatible with windows 7 ultimate service pack 1 32 bits from where I will download it share link what is the procedure step by step to install blender.

Answer (score 2):

The foundation has a [Requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) web page where they discuss this.  Specifically about Windows 7 they say:

> Since Blender 2.93 Windows 7 is no longer supported. Microsoft discontinued Windows 7 support in January 2020

So, any version prior to 2.93 can be downloaded from the [previous versions](https://download.blender.org/release/) page.  Download, unzip, and run.  Be sure to pick the Windows version.

But I *strongly* recommend upgrading Windows.  7 has many bugs that are security risks.  If you put a Windows 7 system on the internet it is likely to be compromised .

Comment: Sir I download blender 2.79b but it not works on windows 7 ultimate service pack 1 32 bits kindly help me.

Comment: @harjinder did you download [this version](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/blender-2.79b-windows32.zip)?  If so, what did you do next, and what error are you getting?  Also, you might want to try [this version](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/blender-2.79b-windows32.msi) instead.  You don't unzip that one you just run it. It will install 2.79b